# SQL Server 2005 Express successfully installed, but is nowhere to be found!

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've SQL Server 2008 Express installed. I've just download and installed **SQL Server 2005 Express**, but I changed the name of instance into SQLEXPRESS2005 (I added 2005 at the end to avoid conflicting names).

Unfortunately, when I try to access the 2005 instance either using the SQL Server Management Studio or the VWD 2008 Express (Database Explorer window), I don't see it.

I just disk-recovered my system, so I lost many of my files. But, before that, I had both versions, one having 2005 as instance name.

So here are the summary of the issues:

1. I was able to download and install successfully the Express 2005
2. When I try to connect to a server, I only see.\SQLEXPRESS as option (there's no SQLEXPRESS2005)
3. When I try to connect from the VWD, I get the ***Server not found ERROR!***
4. I can see the SQL SERVER 2005 icon on the Control Panel window. But, when I try to
   uninstall it, I get a error message telling that this ***program is not found***
5. When do **Start -> All Programs**, I can see the The ***Microsoft SQL Server 2005*** folder

It's really strange as I was successfully  able to install both versions before I experienced problem with my system.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you see the service for the SQLEXPRESS2005 instance?  If it isn't there then the instance doesn't exist and you'll need to reinstall.

Comment: start->run. Type services.msc Look for a service name of SQL Server (instance name) if its not in there, as mrdenny says. you'll need to reinstall.

Comment: Running SERVICES.MSC, here are what I have seen: (i)SQL Active Directory Helper Service, (ii)SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS), (iii) SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS), (iv) SQL Server Browser (SQLEXPRESS), and SQL Server VSS Writer. There's no SQLEXPRESS2005. Then, I'm gonna have to re-install.

Thanks guys. I'm about to give you credit for your answers. However, I still would like to know why when I I go to "Start" menu, I see the SQL Server 2005 folder???! (I'm sorry to add one more question to avoid creating to many threads.)

Comment: Because the instance SQLEXPRESS is installed and that instance is SQL Server 2005.